# Unable to start VSPerfDrv100. This driver has been blocked from loading

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I need to do profiling in visual studio 2010 and 2012 and I try to enable it,
but then I get this error. I am not sure why it does this, I am actually logged in as
administrator.

[image]

Edit: I use Windows 8.

Thanks

Comment: The "from an elevated environment" part of the message is key.  Elevation is a UAC term, you are not elevated even if you login as an admin.  Right-click the command prompt shortcut, click "Run as administrator"

Comment: Why are you using the VS2010 driver but tagged the question with [visual-studio-2012]?  At least try using VSPerfDrv110.  There's also a known compatibility problem with VS2010-SP1 and Windows 8 so don't forget to document your Windows version.

Comment: Yes I used Windows 8.

Comment: The recommended workaround for that compatibility problem is to use VS2012.

Comment: Well I do use VS2012, it is just that on the screen in my post you see the time I tried to make it work for VS2010, but I have the same problem for 2012.

Comment: I'm worn out from trying to pull those teeth.  Good luck with it.